# Cannot use Object Aid in Eclipse 2021

Tags: java, objectaid

I tried to use Object Aid to generate diagram from a code but when I clicked the finish button nothing happen.Do you know how to fix this? Thank you.
[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYw7T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I experimented the same. Only Eclipse versions < 4.19 allow objectAid to work correctly.